# Can't intall lxml, using Enthought Canopy, it wants VBS 2008

Tags: python, xslt, enthought

Preface: I'm pretty new to CLI and Python, know nearly nothing about Canopy, and haven't been able to search my way out of this problem.

Trying to install lxml (required for a class assignment) via pip, and Canopy errors saying it can't find the `xslt-config` command, but continues. Later it really chokes/locks on error of not finding Visual Studio 2008, but offers 'Try MinGW as a work around'. Their suggested command returns a 'can't find setup.py' error, and I can't figure out where MinGW is located to \look in that directory.

**TL;DR** - lxml install seems to fail due to xslt-config problem, b/c Canopy wants Visual Studio 2008 after that. Please help me get lxml working.

Initial chunk of the terminal response follows:

```
Downloading lxml-3.3.5.tar.gz (3.5Mb): 3.5Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
Building lxml version 3.3.5.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
* make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
```

The code goes thru that a couple times/variations, then continues and copies a number of things until it gets to this chunk:

```
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
C:\Users\Owninator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.0.193
8.win-x86\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: '
bugtrack_url'

warnings.warn(msg)

error: Could not find Visual Studio 2008 in your path.
```

It offers

```
To use the MinGW compiler to build an extension module, use
the '-c' flag, e.g.:
python setup.py build_ext -c mingw64
```

However, when I install MinGW and use that command, I get an error that it can't find setup.py.

Comment: Since you say you need it for a class, you are presumably a student, which means you are probably eligible for an academic license, which means that you can get lxml from the package manager as jonathanrocher suggests below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way to install `lxml` in Canopy is to use the package manager. It is accessible from the welcome screen, or from the `Tools > Package manager` menu entry. Make sure you have "Available packages" selected on the menu to the left of the package manager and in the search box, type lxml. It will give you a little button to install it.

Comment: That is the way I eventually fixed this problem. Don't understand the how/why, but Canopy required a second log in to access the packages (this was non-obvious, login is blue text in upper right).